# How to get a column from a text file using php

Tags: php, csv

I want to select specific column of a text file. I'm using PHP. The content of that file is

```
F: TC#              Alpha      1 A                   Z  
F: TC#              Alpha      2 A                   Z  
F: TC#              Alpha      3 A                   Z  
F: TC#              Alpha      1 0                   3
```

Now I want to select the entire columns which content 3 A. How I able to do it using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Your file is space-delimited?  Just use `explode()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$line = 'Joe Jack Jill Jimmy Jerom Jolly Jecob Jason Jasper';
$cols = explode(' ', $line);

echo $cols[1]; // Will return "Jack"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) (in case there's many lines in that file).

```
<?php
$lines = file('file.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $line);
    echo isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : 'N/A' ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fh = fopen('textfile.txt', 'r'); // open input file
$line= fgets($fh); // get a line from the file
$second = (preg_split("/[\s]+/", $line))[1]; // get 2nd column in a split by whitespace
fclose($fh); // close file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select on the *plain occurance* of the string `3 A` in a line, you could do this:

```
$search = "3 A";
$matches = array();
$fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
  $line = fgets($fp, 4096);
  if (strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
    $matches[] = $line;
  }
}
print_r($matches); // voila
```

if the occurance of `3 A` must be in a *specific column*, things are getting more complicated. You have to split each line ("row") to an array which contains an element for each "column".

You could do so by exploding the string by the space character (or tab? how does the file look like?), but this can be faulty. It *will* be faulty when `3 A` is contained in a single "column".

If it's a fixed width table (and your example looks like), find the length of each field and cut the lines in pieces.
Example:

```
// how long is each field?
$field_legths = array(20, 11, 22, 3);

$conditions = array();
$conditions[2] = "3 A"; // search "3 A" in 3rd field (index 2)

$matches = array();
$fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
  $line = fgets($fp, 4096);

  // split line into row array
  $cursor_pos = 0;
  $row = array();
  foreach ($field_legths as $length) {
    $row[] = trim(substr($line, $curser_pos, $length));
    $cursor_pos += $length;
  }

  // search row array for conditions
  foreach ($conditions as $index => $search) {
     if ($row[$index] == $search) {
       $matches[] = $row;
       break;
     }
  }
}
print_r($matches); // voila
```

Make adjustments for the actual table layout. For example, if `3` and `A` represent different columns, make this change:

```
// how long is each field?
$field_legths = array(20, 11, 2, 20, 3);

$conditions = array();
$conditions[2] = "3";
$conditions[3] = "A";
```